# backup website data(image file, database) no downtime

Tags: nginx, backup, vps, postgresql

I have a website using nodejs, postgresql, nginx and runnning on linode vps, I know linode have service backup,
but I want to know if I don't use that,
Q1: how to do manual backup and without downtime?

backup data:

```
image files from user create in application  
postgresql database data from use create in application
```

Q2: I'm newbie, wondering usually people how to do such thing?
Q3: big website(image host) like instagram, imgur  how to do backup?

I google a long time can' find answer, any suggestion will be appreciate!!

UPDATE: 
I know I can dump database, and things like scp download file but I'm not sure is it ok during the application running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is far too broad and lacks details. Do you want to back up a database, static files, and operating system image, or something else? What have you tried yourself? Here's a few generic ideas to get you started.

1. You can do a database dump, then copy that file anywhere you like. You can rsync files anywhere. You can sync files to dropbox. You can do a backup with something like Attic, which gives you deduplicated compressed incremental backups, and then copy those files elsewhere. If you run in AWS you can take a snapshot of entire disks. My AWS server has snapshots taken occasionally, plus every night at midnight I do database dumps, attic backups, then copy those files to Dropbox.
2. It depends.
3. They may not do a backup as such, they may have replication between data centers. They could store a lot of resources on Amazon S3 or similar, enable versioning, then you can't lose your files. They may use Amazon Glacier. They may use any of the techniques in #1.

If you don't know what you're doing you should hire a professional to advise you.

**Update**
You need to read the documentation for your database. In general you must have the database running to do a database dump, as far as I understand anyway. Regular queries still execute. It's possible you may get an inconsistent database backup if transactions modify the database during a dump, unless the dump is inside a transaction. It may slow your server slightly when this the dump is running, so choose an off-peak period to do this if possible.

You may be best off backing up database transaction logs and taking less regular backups. You may be best off doing database replication. There are many options, but to choose between them you need someone to understand your setup, your application, and your aims.

Comment: thanks for reply, sorry for my question was not clear, I already know how to use database dump, and rsync files... I want know is it ok doing these during application running, if when database dump application still can execute database crud query ?

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your clarification. Short answer: read the manual, do some research.

Comment: An alternative to the dump (which can take quite long for big databases) is to quiesce the database (complete all currently running transactions, flush all writes to permanent storage) and then take block-level snapshots of the file system. As long as both your storage and your database are ACID-compliant, you have a consistent backup.